# C++: Executing command and returning output results in assertion failure

Tags: android, c++, assertions

I am working on a project that requires me to programmatically install an Android .apk using `adb install`. I also need to get the result output to use later on. I have the following generic function to execute a command and return the output as a string:

```
std::string exec(const char* command) {
    std::string output = "";
    const int bufferSize = 100;

    FILE *pipe;
    char buffer[bufferSize];

    pipe = _popen(command, "r");
    if (pipe == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }
    while (fgets(buffer, bufferSize, pipe) != NULL) {
        output += buffer;
    }
    _pclose(pipe);

    return output;
}
```

While the command executes and returns the output properly, I get the following error when executing `adb install` using this function:

> Debug Assertion Failed!
>
> Program: ...(My .exe) File:
>   minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\lowio\read.cpp Line: 258
>
> Expression: static_cast(source_buffer) ==
>   static_cast(result_buffer)

I searched for this error online and turned up nothing. The following is the line that causes the assertion failure:

```
while (fgets(buffer, bufferSize, pipe) != NULL) {
```

Can anyone tell me what's going on here, and I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Got the same issue, and fixed by set mode to binary(add 'b'):

```
_popen(myBuffer, "rb");
```

> **Note** that only "r" is enough for Linux and MacOS, and even MSVC 2010.
>
> Hence, seems to be yet another MSVC 2015 bug, and may be fixed in future MSVC versions.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following is relevant (from the microsoft docs)

> If used in a Windows program, the _popen function returns an invalid
>   file pointer that causes the program to stop responding indefinitely.
>   _popen works properly in a console application. To create a Windows application that redirects input and output, see Creating a Child
>   Process with Redirected Input and Output in the Windows SDK.

Try the following https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms682499

Comment: I don't think this is it; the project is a console application, and _popen seems to work properly. Even with adb install, the command executes and returns its output ok - only adb install also causes the assertion failure. Thank you.